# Spring concurrent session control error disappears after page refresh

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

my flow:

1. Start a session for User1 in browser1 (session1)
2. Login as User1 in browser2 (session2)
3. Refresh the page in browser1 - error is displayed:
   'This session has been expired (possibly due to multiple concurrent logins being attempted as the same user)
4. Refresh the page in browser1 once again - the old session is successfully restored

how can I over session1?

My spring config:

```
<session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"/>
</session-management>
```

Comment: _5. Refresh page in browser2 - you'll see error is displayed: 'This session has been expired'_ 
That's how it works, to see an alternative solution set `error-if-maximum-exceeded` to `true` and until you session in browser1 expires you won't be able to log in on browser2.

Comment: but if i want allow to login one more time, but destroy previous login session? Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible, in fact it's exactly what's going on - when you do _4._, a **new** session is created in browser1.

Comment: yes, but in fact it not destroyed, because you can refresh page and session will restore, what is inappropriate for me

Comment: Session will **not** restore, **new** one is going to be created. It's the same scenario as described above: in _2._ session1 is marked as expired when you login in browser2 and create session2. Then when you login in browser1 again, you get information about invalid (expired) session, but after refreshing browser1, session2 is marked as expired, and session3 in browser1 is created. You can repeat the process, that's how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it does that it uses remember me login to login you again.You can redirect your expired session to another  url as given below and expire the current session manually

### In security config:

(just add expired url attribute )

```
.sessionManagement().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(concurrentSessionControlStrategy)
   .maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false).expiredUrl("/users/expire-me")
```

### In fwd api/url:

```
@RequestMapping(value="expire-me", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void expireSession(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    request.getSession(false).invalidate();
}
```

This is what I did and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

(Another work around)you must be using remember me authentication also, that's how your first browser re-logins. If you expect it to work properly,DON'T use `remember-me`.